# How can I configure a TeamsFx app to run behind a corporate proxy?

Tags: teams-toolkit

Currently, when I try to debug my app locally using `teamsfx preview --local`, I cannot get the app to start. The app in question is the hello world example taken from the documentation so I don't believe this is related to how the app itself is structured.

To be more specific, after running the command I get the status bars loading on my console, but after everything goes to 100%, it stays that way, without giving me any more feedback:

```
$ teamsfx preview --local
████████████████████  100% | [1/1] Node.js (√) Done.  
████████████████████  100% | [2/2] M365 Account (√) Done.  
████████████████████  100% | [2/2] Development certificate for localhost (√) Done.  
████████████████████  100% | [2/2] Ngrok (√) Done.  
████████████████████  100% | [1/1] Ports (√) Done.  
████████████████████  100% | [1/1] bot npm install (√) Done.  
ngrok start: The log of this task can be found in: C:\Users\<my_user>\.fx\cli-log\local-preview\2022-04-18T14_44_37_066Z\ngrok-start.log 
████████████████████  100% | [1/1] ngrok start (√) Done.  
████████████████████  100% | [1/1] bot npm install (√) Done.  
████████████████████  100% | [3/3] Provisioning Azure AD app (√) Done.  
████████████████████  100% | [1/1] Local debugging (√) Done.
```

I have my proxy configured in Windows settings and have set the `proxy` and `http-proxy` variables on my .npmrc file. Is there someplace else I need to specify my proxy address? Or is the problem something I'm missing entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the ngrok behind proxy is not successfully started. Do you find something in the ngrok log file?

> C:\Users<my_user>.fx\cli-log\local-preview\2022-04-18T14_44_37_066Z\ngrok-start.log

How to solve this problem:

1. Solve the ngrok issue and then run `teamsfx preview --local` again.
2. Or you can use your own tunneling service instead of ngrok. See [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/blob/dev/docs/fx-core/localdebug-help.md#what-to-do-if-i-want-to-use-my-own-tunneling-service-instead-of-the-built-in-one-for-bot-or-messaging-extension) for the configuration.

Comment: Hi Kuoijan, thanks for the answer!
I've since managed to get this working on very specific conditions and I'm trying to make my way back to see if I can get things running on the usual network configs. Pretty nice to know that I can use my own tunneling service instead of ngrok, that's gonna be really helpful for me down the line.